# Xcode (Swift) on Ubuntu?

Tags: gui

A while ago I read I can develop with Swift in Linux but now can't find a good way to do so, I've been using Xcode & Swift 5. While there are ways to write with Swift one important factor for me is GUI development, is there any way to do this in Ubuntu ?

Comment: I have looked around a lot for this problem, but sadly haven't been able to find a proper solution. Apple has somewhat of a walled garden around iOS development.

Answer (score 2):

Install [jetbrain's `CLion`](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/)

It's requires payment after 30 days though but it's worth it.
It's what I am using to develop beginner Swift since I am very new to the language (Less than a week).

Answer (score 1):

If you are a college student, you can get a free JETBRAINS student license that is valid till the end of your IT related course.
There you'll be able to download CLion.
If you're a linux user like I or Mac, you'll be able to install via the jetbrains toolbox or via the .tar file from the jetbrains.com site
For windows, its pretty much the same thing. you'll follow instructions from the website.
The license is renewable every after 1 year till you finish your uni.
You can do this by using the github student pack resource
Direct link is https://www.jetbrains.com/community/education/#students

Answer (score 0):

> one important factor for me is GUI development, is there any way to do this in Ubuntu?

For GUI-based Development Enviroments, consider:

- [Geany](https://www.geany.org/) … *[release 1.36.0 added Swift language filetype](https://www.geany.org/documentation/releasenotes/)*
- JetBrains' [CLion Swift plugin](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/swift.html)
- [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with the ["Swift for Visual Code"](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sswg.swift-lang) extension.
- [VSCodium](https://vscodium.com/) with ["Swift" extensions](https://open-vsx.org/?search=swift)

For GUI Application Development, the following could be of interest:

- [Various Swift + GTK Repositories](https://github.com/search?o=desc&q=language%3Aswift+GTK&s=stars&type=Repositories)
- [OpenSwiftUI](https://github.com/Cosmo/OpenSwiftUI) an OpenSource implementation of Apple's SwiftUI DSL.

*Related Swift forum discussion:*

- [search "GTK"](https://forums.swift.org/search?q=GTK)
- ["Hacking Swift runtime"](https://forums.swift.org/t/hacking-swift-runtime/42289) ... Swift wrapper for GTK thread
- ["SwiftUI for non-Apple platforms (like Android, Web, Windows)"](https://forums.swift.org/t/swiftui-for-non-apple-platforms-like-android-web-windows/25455/95)